# Validation with ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ado.net

I have an asp.net mvc3 w/ ado.net entity framework doing some validation.

I have created a viewmodel as such

```
public class id
{


    [Required]
    public decimal l_ID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Required]
    public decimal v_ID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to add some set of validation rules so that the l_id must be larger than the v_id? validation should be done once the user has submitted the page. How would this be done? Any tutorials? Does this validation need to be done in the controller or using partial classes? Is there any examples out there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been using the IValidatable interface, its fairly simple compared to custom attribute validation. Here's the code:

```
public class id : IValidatableObject
    {
        [Required]
        public decimal l_ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public decimal v_ID { get; set; }

        private bool _hasBeenValidated = false;

        public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {

            if (!_hasBeenValidated)
            {
                // validation rules go here. 
                if (l_ID <= v_ID)
                    yield return new ValidationResult("Bad thing!", new string[] { "l_ID" });
            }

            _hasBeenValidated = true;
        }
    }
```

Couple of notes, the Validate method is called automatically when the binding occurs from a POST action that takes the ViewModel as a parameter, so you don't have to do any wiring up of events. The `bool _hasBeenValidated` thing is in there because right now there's a quasi bug in MVC3 (imho) that calls that validation method twice in some cases (*like when this ViewModel is also used as a member of another ViewModel and that gets posted*)

The second param of the ValidationResult constuctor is the name of the property that the validation is bound to, so in this case, your ValidatorFor tag for the l_ID in your View would get that "Bad thing" message in it.

Comment: Great! That worked. Just a quick follow up question. If i wanted to compare the user inputting v_ID to a parameter that has been passed in from the URL, how would the validation rule change, how would i get that parameter from the browser.

Comment: Is the URL param part of the ViewModel, or can it be? That's how I'd do it. The ViewModel should hold everything the 'page' needs to run its operations. Once everything is in the ViewModel, the Validate method can just look at those fields to do its logic. Post back here with a specific scenerio, or open up a newer, more specific question (and let me know).

Comment: yes i added two fields such as old_v_id and old_l_id to the viewmodel, and i should be able to work with this now. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

ViewModel exist in MVVM pattern, for you and MVC you use Controller, Model and View

Yes you can add DataAnnotation in your Model.

Link : http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-%28data%29/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs

Comment: Hey, i have checked that out previously which is why i have the [Required] statements, but what im asking is how can I have conditional validation

Comment: There is a place for ViewModels in MVC but their meaning is different than ViewModels in MVVM. It's just a variation of DTO.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom validation attribute - there's is plenty of help on the web. The following is an adaptation from a similar dependant attribute.

```
public class GreaterThanOtherAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    public string DependentProperty { get; set; }

    public GreaterThanOtherAttribute (string dependentProperty)
    {
        this.DependentProperty = dependentProperty;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        // get a reference to the property this validation depends upon
        var containerType = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType();
        var field = containerType.GetProperty(this.DependentProperty);

        if (field != null)
        {
            // get the value of the dependent property
            var dependentvalue = field.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

            // compare the value against the target value
            if ((dependentvalue == null && this.TargetValue == null) ||
                (dependentvalue != null && dependentvalue < this.TargetValue)))
            {
                // match => means we should try validating this field
                return new ValidationResult(this.ErrorMessage, new[] { validationContext.MemberName });
            }
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
```

and then decorate your model:

```
public class id           
{      
    [Required]           
    public decimal l_ID           
    {           
        get;           
        set;           
    }           

    [Required]   
    [GreaterThanOtherAttribute("l_ID")]        
    public decimal v_ID           
    {           
        get;           
        set;           
    }           
}
```

What you now need to do is to find an example custom attribute and adapt it to use the above.

HEALTH WARNING - this is not tested in any way and probably contains error.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use the [Fluent Validation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) component. It can be [integrated with Asp.Net MVC](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc&referringTitle=Documentation) and you could add easily some validation rules using a fluent sintaxe. DataAnnotations works fine too, but I do not like because it pollutes your domain model or viewmodel. I like to create a separate responsibilities structure.